# What could be a reason of timeout exception using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm getting this error from time to time performing operations with `StackExchange.Redis 1.2.0.0` on **Azure Redis** from ASP.NET app running on Azure App Service:

`Timeout performing EXISTS bookmark:afad5065-29b1-48c7-8bbc-38ddcc9ab4e4type:1, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 0, qs: 3, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: mywebapp, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/myapp.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 8377, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=200,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=200,Max=32767), Local-CPU: unavailable (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md) System.TimeoutException`

Connecting with the following configuration: `allowAdmin=true,ssl=true,abortConnect=false,connectTimeout=5000,syncTimeout=2000`.

Neither client machine nor Redis service does not experience high load in that time.
Have read about [timeouts](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Timeouts.md) already but still have no idea what is causing them in my case. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Azure documentation specifically for Azure Redis? I would start here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

Comment: Have you net traffic to redis? All ports open? Is your IP on Redis ACL? If configured.

Comment: @AndySinclair, yes I've already tried several recommendations from that article but no success. I'm feeling that I'm missing some subtle point in all this.

Answer (score 2):

Timeouts can be caused by [client-side](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md) or [server-side](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/9225f783a40564c9879d#file-diagnoserediserrors-serverside-md) performance problems, so you have to look at both sides to determine what would be causing it for your application.

Some things to consider:

- When looking at client or server side perf counters in the azure portal, be careful to look at a relatively small time window (e.g. 1 hour).  This is important because the portal aggregates values when you zoom out to longer time windows and this can hide short-lived spikes in load
- Many performance counters are captured using sampling instead of continuous monitoring, so it is possible that a spike in load is not long enough to show up in the portal.  For instance, if CPU usage is logged every 15 seconds but the spike in CPU is only 5 seconds long, it can happen between samples and will not be seen.  This is why StackExchange.Redis tries to capture the instantaneous CPU usage when it is about to throw a timeout.  Unfortunately, some environments disallow access to system performance counters - thus the "local-cpu: unavailable" message in the timeout error.  To counter this, you can try to capture a dump of your process when the timeout happens.  The dump will typically contain the CPU info at the time the dump was taken.

I have compiled a list of [best practices](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-bestpractices-general-md) that help avoid common pitfalls in Redis.

If you still don't see any clear indication of the problem, open a support case with Azure and they will help you investigate.